# actionscript 3 if array in condition

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, conditional-statements, flash-cs5.5

i want to ask about this code..

```
 if (objek.dropTarget.parent.name == "book")
            {
    if ((objek == alif) || (objek == ba)){  //yg perlu diganti
    //if (objek == objBenar){  //yg perlu diganti
                objek.x = objek.dropTarget.parent.x;
                objek.y = objek.dropTarget.parent.y + 50;
                objek.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);
                objek.buttonMode = false;
                var _loc_2:Number;
                objek.scaleY = 0.4;
                objek.scaleX = _loc_2;
                objek.alpha = 0.6;
                score+=5;
                scorebox.text = "Score: " + score;
            }
            else {
            objek.x = objek.dropTarget.parent.x;
                objek.y = objek.dropTarget.parent.y + 50;
                objek.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);
                objek.buttonMode = false;
                var _loc_2:Number;
                objek.scaleY = 0.4;
                objek.scaleX = _loc_2;
                objek.alpha = 0.6;
                score-=2;
                scorebox.text = "Score: " + score;}
            }

        }
```

i have movieclip alif, ba, and dal..this three can be dragged to movieclip named "book" and the score will change.
if i drag alif and ba movieclip to book, score will increase..
if i drag dal movieclip to book score will decrease..
how if i want to make the movieclip alif and ba of an array??and how to write the condition??
help pliss :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand, but do you want to have an array containing alif and ba and then check if the movieclip is in that array? This is how you would do that:

```
var scoreIncreasers:Array = [alif, ba];
var isScoreIncreaser:Boolean = (scoreIncreasers.indexOf(objeck) !== -1);
if(isScoreIncreaser) {
    // Increase score
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comment, I think this is what you want:

```
var objBener:Array = [alif, ba];
if(objBener.indexOf(objek) !== -1) {
    //yg perlu diganti
}
```

Comment: mmm..i mean like this (sorry if my english is bad :) )
in that script i write 

if ((objek == alif) || (objek == ba)){  //yg perlu diganti

then if i want to put alif and ba in array, eg:
objBener = [alif, ba];

so how i write the condition?? i try 
if (objek == objBener[]) {
but it gets an error..

Comment: So basically, you want to know if objek is alif or ba, but instead of comparing them one by one, you just want to compare once? If that is what you want, then the code above, should work. the indexOf method of an array tells you at what index an object is in an array. If the object is not in the array, then it returns -1. Please see the 2nd example that I added in my answer.